# Using C64 floating point kernal routines with 16 bit integer

Tags: commodore-64, assembly, floating-point

How to use floating point kernal routines for 16 bit arithmetics such as: $1234*$ABCD or $1234/$ABCD ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer (what's your actual question?) and ensure it's actually answerable. See [ask] for guidelines.

Comment: I was just in the middle of writing an answer and it's closed as "too broad". There's no way asking how to convert a 16 bit number to floating point on the C64 is too broad.

Comment: @Digerkam It's a bit difficult to write code in a comment but have a look at the [C64 Wiki](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic). The routine at `$B391` will convert from 16 bit to floating point and the routine at `$B1AA` will convert the other way. And there are other routines for the arithmetic ops.

Comment: @Digerkam The first question here would be why  converting it to FP and doing slow FP when the task itself is about an integer multiplication?

Comment: @Raffzahn I want to use FP and slowness doesnt matter. Do you have any idea how to convert 16 bit value into FP and get the result into 16 bit value again?

Comment: A nitpick: On the C64, the kernal does not do any floating point; only BASIC does.

Comment: @Digerkam This site _is_ actually "a museum", as you put it. That's actually a pretty good description! The page, answers, and comments are here for _collecting information for people who have this question in future_. If you have further concerns, please raise a moderator flag or post a question on [meta]; do not post accusatory comments if you have a problem with someone's behaviour.

Comment: @JeremyP Sorry about that; I was 50/50 between "unclear" and "too broad" but chose "too broad" because it had a more fitting default message.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I don't think it was either: off topic, possibly (it's a straight programming question), but not unclear and not too broad.

Comment: The question was recently edited to change 'kernal' to 'kernel'.  Since this is about a Commodore machine, the incorrect spelling was in fact [the actual name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KERNAL) of the code. Reading 'kernal' causes me physical pain, but it is historically accurate.

Answer (score 14):

There's a great and much detailed [description](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic) at the C64 Wiki (*1) describing the basic structures and workings, as well as all functions involved to use the ROM routines for floating point (*2)

Cookbook:

- Use `GIVAYF` to [convert](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic#Routines_for_converting_between_floating_point_and_other_formats) a 16 Bit number in A:Y into an FP in FAC
- If multiple numbers are involved, [move FAC](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic#Routines_for_moving_.28copying.29_numbers) to memory using `MOVMF`
- Repeat for all numbers
- Do [whatever function](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic#Routines_for_performing_calculations) is needed, like `FMULT` for multiplication (FAC times saved value)
- Use `FACINX` to convert the result from FAC back into a 16 bit in A:Y
- Or `QINT` if you expect the result to need a 32 bit integer - like with a 16x16 multiplication.

As usual, countless variations thereof are possible, depending on the task at hand and requirements set.

---

*1 - Thanks to [JeremyP](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/3297/jeremyp) for that link

*2 - Which BTW are not part of the Kernel, but belong to BASIC [as Wilson pointed out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/using-c64-floating-point-kernal-routines-for-16-bit-values?noredirect=1#comment23392_8059) :))

Comment: You know, you can get much better-looking footnotes by using the `sup` tag, such as `<sup>(1)</sup>`.

Comment: For references, I often use `<sup>[\[1\]][1]</sup>`. That gets old _really_ fast, though; it'd be good if there was built-in support for footnotes and references.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Interesting idea - and ho do you format the footnote itself to be pointed at?

Comment: @Raffzahn There's not a way to make linked footnotes, unfortunately; Stack Exchange ignores ID links like [this one](#anchor) (`[this one](#anchor)`).

Comment: @Digerkam Your response suggests that you are after somebody to write code for you. Generally this is something people are paid to do; might I suggest hiring a programmer?

Comment: You are partialy right: yes if it is an huge code action, or touching any know-how, then I must hire someone. no if it is an simple code problem, or asking voluntary expert help. in SE sites which focusing coding, answers are full of codes, and knowledges which coming from experts without any payment. SE very popular thanks to this volunteer people. or it would be nothing. But you guys quite right about: this is not a forum site. But "Please watch your tone" is not an good calling, and never open nice doors. In the morning it was not this on my mind about FP in C64. Thank you. Regards.

Comment: @Digerkam - the answer here is quite clear even to a non expert. I've never programmed on the C64 (other than simple BASIC stuff), and my experience of 6502 assembly in general is fairly limited (a couple of small projects on the BBC micro), but I'm sure I could turn this into working code within an hour. In general, understanding how something works is more useful than having code to copy and paste because c&p code almost always needs customizing for the application, and if you don't understand it you can't do that. It's hard with most languages but essentially impossible in assembly language

Comment: @Jules You are right, but using FP is very small part of my project, and I stuck in using FP side. Intention of asking the question was not facing more issue than FP usage. I am a software engineer and as you understand I am very bored to recieve life lessons than a few line of code... I am aware of that it is very a few line, but you know, I was looking for someone who experimented FP math and give an faster solution than me. That was the purpose of the question.

Comment: @Digerkam Then why didn't you ask "what's the fastest way of multiplying two 16-bit integers in C64 assembly?" We're not psychic! :-) I recommend reading [ask] before asking questions in future, so you don't have this whole big problem again.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The point was not "fastest way of multiplying" :) It was never! The point is "usage of FP Math routines in C64 ROM for 16 bit values". The question title is obviously there. JeremyP provided usage with an example, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this an addendum to [Raffzahn's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8062/6659). If you are going to accept one, accept his.

The code for your first multiplication might look like this (note I haven't tested this)

```
lda #$12
ldy #$34
jsr GIBAYF
lda some_memory_loc_low_byte
ldy some_memory_loc_highbyte
jsr MOVEFM
lda $AB
ldy $CD
jsr GIBAYF
lda some_memory_loc_low_byte
ldy some_memory_loc_highbyte
jsr FMULT
jsr FACINX ; Answer in A:Y
```

That's going to be a lot slower than doing the 16 bit multiplication directly though.

Comment: As an addendum to this if you look in the Apple ][ technical reference on pages 83/84 there are 16 bit integer multiple and divide routines. https://archive.org/details/applerefjan78/page/n83/mode/2up which you can use.